# C# Regex.Replace, Colon as Delimiter, Ignore DateTime format

Tags: c#, regex, json, datetime

I have the following string:

```
[{names: {en: "US 30 - 5 Minute Level", es: "US 30 - 5 Minute Level"}, status: "A", displayed: "Y", start_time: "2011-05-20 00:00:00", start_time_xls: {en: "20th of May 2011  00:00 am", es: "20 May 2011 00:00 am"}, suspend_at: "2011-05-20 16:53:48", is_off: "Y", score_home: "", score_away: "", bids_status: "", period_id: "", curr_period_start_time: "", score_extra_info: "", settled: "N", ev_id: 2688484, ev_type_id: 10745, num_mkts: 5, venues: {en: "", es: ""}, disporder: 2040, ev_stream_available: false}]
```

I need to surround all the variable names with quotation marks so this will validate as JSON. I was doing the following, but it's also splitting up the dates. .

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"(\w+:)", "\"$0\":", RegexOptions.None);
```

Output after Regex.Replace:

```
[{"names" {"en" "US 30 - 5 Minute Level", "es" "US 30 - 5 Minute Level"}, "status" "A", "displayed" "Y", "start_time" "2011-05-20 "00""00"00", "start_time_xls" {"en" "20th of May 2011 "00"00 am", "es" "20 May 2011 "00"00 am"}, "suspend_at" "2011-05-20 "16""53"48", "is_off" "Y", "score_home" "", "score_away" "", "bids_status" "", "period_id" "", "curr_period_start_time" "", "score_extra_info" "", "settled" "N", "ev_id" 2688484, "ev_type_id" 10745, "num_mkts" 5, "venues" {"en" "", "es" ""}, "disporder" 2040, "ev_stream_available" false}]
```

How can I change this to ignore them? Also, what's a good web-based resource to get to the bottom of Regular Expressions once and for all?!

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Try this pattern:

```
string pattern = @"\b([A-Za-z_]+)\b(?=:)";
string replace = "\"$0\"";
string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, replace);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

The `[A-Za-z_]+` matches any upper/lower-case alphabet and the underscore character one or more times. This works fine if none of the JSON names contain numbers. The `\b` metacharacter matches on a word boundary and `(?=:)` matches - but doesn't capture - a colon. You'll notice that the `replace` pattern doesn't include a colon.

Similarly, this pattern would work: `@"\b([^\d\s]+)\b(?=:)"` since it matches everything that is not a number or space.

Learning regex takes a lot of practice to understand the concepts, try out examples, and wrap your head around how things work. I suggest grabbing a tool that let's you try them out along with some tutorials. To get you started:

- [The 30 Minute Regex Tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/regextutorial.aspx)
- [Regular Expressions Info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) - great resource, explains different concepts and highlights differences between regex engines in various languages.
- [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) - this is a free tool, you just need to provide an email to register it. It also includes the 30 min regex tutorial I linked to above.

That should get you started. If you really want to dive deeper then two good books to check out are:

- [Mastering Regular Expressions](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596528124) - highly recommended
- [Regular Expressions Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596520689)

Comment: Unbelievable. Perfect. The second part of the question was how do I learn to do this myself?!! Would appreciate any pointers to stuff to read.

Comment: Regular expression are challenging to learn (or at least they are for me). I found that RegEx Buddy is really helpful for me. It provides you with sytax in many different languages as well as debugging and testing capabilities. Check it out here: http://www.regexbuddy.com/

Comment: @Tomás updated with some links. There are some online regex testers too, but I don't use them much. A search should yield some results. RegexBuddy is a good tool as @Brian mentioned, but it's not free.